# find the min and max value in two columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have some data which looks like:

```
sampleA    ATGC    10   100
sampleA    ATGC    120  230
sampleA    ATGC    200  110
```

I want to print the min and max using the values in both column 3 and 4. So my output should look like:

```
sampleA   10  230
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to print the min value from column 3 only and the max value from column 4 only?  Or if column 3 was: 1000, 120, 200 and column 4 was 100, 230, 10 would you want your results to be: `sampleA 1000 10`?

Comment: The max or min could be in column 3 or 4. Because this is DNA ORF information some reads are in reverse like the last line in the above example.

Comment: So in that case I believe both answers below wont work.  NVM just noticed AFSHIN edited his answer.

Comment: awk's `asort` function will do the job

Comment: It appears that columns 1 and 2 have absolutely *nothing* to do with the output.  Are the column 1 values identical in all rows?  If not, I don't see how you can even define what the first field of output should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline; min=$3;max=$4}
          {(min>$3)?min=$3:"";(max>$4)?"":max=$4}
     END{print min, max}' infile.txt
```

The output is:

```
10 230
```

But I guess you are looking for something like below to find min/max within 2Columns not min in 3rd Column and max in 4th Column only as above is finding.

Sample Input:

```
sampleA    ATGC    10    100
sampleA    ATGC    300   2
sampleA    ATGC    200   1100
sampleA    ATGC    2301  9
sampleA    ATGC    12345 15
sampleA    ATGC    235   7
```

The command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline;min=max=$3;
           ($4>$3)?max=$4:min=$4} {
           ($3>$4 && min>$4)?min=$4:((min>$3)?min=$3:"");
           ($3>$4 && $3>max)?max=$3:((max<$4)?max=$4:"");
} END{print min, max}' infile.txt
```

The output would be:

```
2 12345
```

Answer (score 3):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ a[++c]=$3; a[++c]=$4 }END{ asort(a); print $1,a[1],a[length(a)] }' file
```

The output:

```
sampleA 10 230
```

---

Short [***datamash***](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) solution (for separate min/max calculation within 3rd/4th columns):

```
datamash -W -g1 min 3 max 4 < file
```

- `-g1` - group records by 1st column value
- `min 3` - get minimum value on 3rd column
- `max 4` - get maximum value on 4rd column

The output:

```
sampleA 10  230
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `datamash`! does it can find the min/max within 2columns as OP is clarified?

Comment: @AFSHIN, see my short update

Answer (score 0):

```
NF == 4 {
    if (++totalSamples == 1) {
        sampleName = $1
        minValue   = $3;
        maxValue   = $3;
    } else {
        if ($3 < minValue)
            minValue = $3
        else if ($3 > maxValue)
            maxValue = $3
    }
    if ($4 < minValue)
        minValue = $4
    else if ($4 > maxValue)
        maxValue = $4
}

END {
    if (totalSamples)
        printf("%s    %d   %d\n", sampleName, minValue, maxValue)
}
```