# Extract maximum values for each objects from a file

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data, statistics

I need to extract some values from a file in `bash`, on my CentOS system. In `myfile.txt` I have a list of objects called `Info_region` in which each object is identified with a code (eg. `BARD1_region_005` or `BIRC2_region_002` etc.) Moreover there are some others columns in which are reported some numerical variable. The same object (same code name) can be repeated several times in my file.
I also have a file that contains a completed list with all object codes without duplicates.
I would like to obtain an output.txt file in which each object (code name) is reported only once as in my list-file.txt and I would like to associate to this the maximum possible values associated with that code name in myfile.txt.

myfile.txt: (columns are separated by `tab`)

```
Info_region Lig_score   Lig_prevista    Lig_prevista_+1 Int_score   Expo_score  Protac_score
BARD1_region_005    0   3   3   0   1   1
BARD1_region_006    0   1   1   0   1   1
BIRC2_region_001    1   6   7   0   1   2
BIRC2_region_001    1   7   8   0   1   2
BIRC2_region_001    0   2   2   0   0   0
BIRC2_region_001    0   12  12  0   1   1
BIRC2_region_001    1   10  11  -1  1   1
BIRC2_region_001    1   2   3   0   1   2
BIRC2_region_001    1   0   1   0   1   2
BIRC2_region_001    1   6   7   0   1   2
BIRC2_region_002    0   0   0   0   1   1
BIRC2_region_002    1   0   0   -1  0.5 0.5
BIRC2_region_003    0   0   0   0   1   1
BIRC2_region_004    0   1   1   0   1   1
UHRF1_region_004    0   0   0   1   1   2
UHRF1_region_004    0   0   0   1   1   2
UHRF1_region_004    1   0   1   0   0.5 1.5
UHRF1_region_004    0   0   0   1   1   2
UHRF1_region_005    0   3   3   1   1   2
UHRF1_region_005    1   0   0   -1  1   1
```

file-list.txt:

```
Info_region
BARD1_region_005
BARD1_region_006
BIRC2_region_001
BIRC2_region_002
BIRC2_region_003
BIRC2_region_004
UHRF1_region_004
UHRF1_region_005
```

output.txt:

```
Info_region Lig_score   Lig_prevista    Lig_prevista_+1 Int_score   Expo_score  Protac_score
BARD1_region_005    0   3   3   0   1   1
BARD1_region_006    0   1   1   0   1   1
BIRC2_region_001    1   12  12  0   1   2
BIRC2_region_002    1   0   0   0   1   1
BIRC2_region_003    0   0   0   0   1   1
BIRC2_region_004    0   1   1   0   1   1
UHRF1_region_004    1   0   1   1   1   2
UHRF1_region_005    1   3   3   1   1   2
```

Could someone help me please? Thank you!

Comment: do you mean the maximum per column (field)? 
where an Info_region occurs more than once in the original file, should the values per column be added or considered separately?

Comment: Is there anything you have tried? There are similar questions here where you can find good information ([e.g.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384931/find-the-min-and-max-value-in-two-columns)). Hint: `awk` or `datamash` should do.

Comment: What do you mean by "bash" exactly? Using bash or any shell for text [processing is not a good idea. Do you really mean you want to use bash or are you OK with tools like sed, awk, etc? Do you just mean you want a command line solution or does it _really_ need to be bash for some reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the data is in the file called `file` and that it is sorted on the first column, the GNU `datamash` utility could do this in one go on the data file alone:

```bsh
datamash -H -W -g 1 max 2-7 <file
```

This instructs the utility to use whitespace separated columns (`-W`; remove this if your column are truly tab-delimited), that the first line of the data contains headers (`-H`), to group by he first column (`-g 1`), and to calculate the maximum values for the 2nd through to the 7th columns.

The result, given the data in the question:

```
GroupBy(Info_region)    max(Lig_score)  max(Lig_prevista)       max(Lig_prevista_+1)    max(Int_score)     max(Expo_score) max(Protac_score)
BARD1_region_005        0       3       3       0       1       1
BARD1_region_006        0       1       1       0       1       1
BIRC2_region_001        1       12      12      0       1       2
BIRC2_region_002        1       0       0       0       1       1
BIRC2_region_003        0       0       0       0       1       1
BIRC2_region_004        0       1       1       0       1       1
UHRF1_region_004        1       0       1       1       1       2
UHRF1_region_005        1       3       3       1       1       2
```

You could also use `--header-in` in place of `-H` to get header-less output, and then take the header from the original data file:

```bsh
{ head -n 1 file; datamash --header-in -W -g 1 max 2-7 <file; } >output
```

Here, I'm also writing the result to some new output file called `output`.

---

Using `awk` and assuming tab-delimited fields:

```bsh
awk -F '\t' '
    BEGIN { OFS = FS }
    NR == 1 { print; next }
    {
        n[$1] = 1
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
            a[$1,i] = (a[$1,i] == "" || $i > a[$1,i] ? $i : a[$1,i])
    }
    END { 
        nf = NF
        for (j in n) {
            $0 = j
            for (i = 2; i <= nf; ++i)
                $i = a[$1,i]
            print
         }
     }' file
```

This calculates the maximum value in each column for each group.  These numbers are stored in the `a` array while the `n` array just holds the group names as keys.

Comment: If my columns are separeated by tab? I can modify the script?

Comment: I have a problem.....bash: datamash: command not found

Comment: @TommasoPalomba The output is tab delimited. It does not matter if you use tabs or spaces for the input. If you don't have `datamash`, you may have to install it or ask for it to be installed (I have compiled it for myself without needing to be root).

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you don't actually want to do this in bash (and you shouldn't), but are willing to use other tools. Here's a GNU`awk` approach:

```
$ gawk -vOFS="\t" -F'\t' \
    '{ 
        if(NR==1){print; } 
        else{ 
            for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ 
                if($i > a[$1][i] || ! a[$1][i]){a[$1][i]=$i}
           }
        } 
     }
     END{ 
        for (region in a){ 
            printf "%s", region; 
            for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ 
                printf "%s%s", OFS,a[region][i]
            } 
            printf "\n";  
        } 
     }' myfile.txt 
Info_region Lig_score   Lig_prevista    Lig_prevista_+1 Int_score   Expo_score  Protac_score
BIRC2_region_001    1   12  12  0   1   2
BIRC2_region_002    1   0   0   -1  1   1
BIRC2_region_003    0   0   0   0   1   1
BIRC2_region_004    0   1   1   0   1   1
BARD1_region_005    0   3   3   0   1   1
BARD1_region_006    0   1   1   0   1   1
UHRF1_region_004    1   0   1   1   1   2
UHRF1_region_005    1   3   3   1   1   2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach using neither true multidimensional arrays nor emulated multi-dimensional. Instead , we Store chunks in the same key.

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS = FS = "\t" }
NR==1 { print; next }
{
  obj = $1; $1=""; sub(FS, "")
  a[obj] = a[obj] $0 FS
}
END {
  nf0 = NF
  for (obj in a) {
    $1 = obj
    nf = split(a[obj], f)
    for (i=1; i<=nf0; i++) {
      $(i+1) = f[i]
      for (j=0; j<int(nf/nf0); j++) {
        idx = i + nf0*j
        if ( f[idx] > $(i+1) ) $(i+1) = f[idx]
      }
    }
    print
  }
}
' myfile.txt
```